# Why won't my putty window stay aero snapped?

Tags: multiple-monitors, putty, aero-snap

I have a two monitor win 7 setup, and typically run with three putty sessions open in separate windows. I have one snapped to the LHS of my LHS monitor, one snapped to the RHS of my LHS monitor and the last snapped to the LHS of my RHS monitor.

My problem is that the putty window snapped to the RHS of my LHS monitor frequently increases in size so that is expands into the RHS monitor area.

Any idea how to stop this? Really irritating. Odd that it only seems to occur with middle putty window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using old PuTTY version, try the newer one [download link](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

My co-worker had issue with putty windows not snapping to the sides of screens using <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>, and updating putty to v0.63 helped.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Oh, I see... I'll remember this. Thank you for guidance and kind welcome!